# Constructor as a key in a hashmap?

Tags: java

```
//Represents a seat on a plane.
public class Seat {

    //The section that the seat is in.
    public int sectionId;
    public int seatId;

    public Seat(int seatId, int sectionId) {
        this.seatId = seatId;
        this.sectionId = sectionId;
    }

}
```

The above just contains the "settings" I guess for each seat. I'm attempting to call the constructor in a map to pair each unique seat with a seat type (adult/child)/ here is what I came up with:

```
   public enum SeatType {
    ADULT,
    CHILD;
}

private static Map<Seat, SeatType> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sectionId = 5;
    map.put(new Seat(1, 5), SeatType.ADULT);
    System.out.println(map.get(new Seat(1, 5)));
```

execution of this code out prints "null" to the console. I know I could easily create a new object for each seat but that's not really an option as that would mean I'd have to create 200+ objects.

I wasn't expecting it to work but I was looking for an explanation on why it doesn't and perhaps a possible resolution to the problem.

Thanks in advance!(And sorry, still a beginner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your `Seat` class. Try changing your `Seat` class to the following:

```
public class Seat {

  public int sectionId;
  public int seatId;

  public Seat(int seatId, int sectionId) {
    this.seatId = seatId;
    this.sectionId = sectionId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Seat seat = (Seat) o;
    if (sectionId != seat.sectionId) return false;
    return seatId == seat.seatId;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = sectionId;
    result = 31 * result + seatId;
    return result;
  }
}
```

This resolves the issue because the `hashCode` method plays an important role in adding and looking up your value as the key to a `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, `HashSet`, etc. If you override `hashCode`, you should also override `equals`, and vice versa.

Take a look at the following questions for more information:

- [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)